# Some code search tools for Gerrit to match keyword

Tags: git, gerrit

I want a tool to search code line based on keywords such as function names and macros in multiple projects in gerrit, and only show matching lines instead of the entire file, because the code has different permission allocation policies

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to take a look at the [OpenGrok](https://github.com/oracle/opengrok) - a wicked fast source browser.

Comment: Opengrok seems to support looking at everything in the source file, and I expect to see only the matching lines. In addition, does this tool support the export of matching results? If possible, I will consider revising the source code to view the full source code feature.

Comment: When you search for something in OpenGrok first it only shows the matching lines, after that you can click in any line/file to get more details. I didn't find a way to export only the matching lines.